# Invalid use of register error when using inc with esi

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have the following assembly code :

```
.data
string_2 BYTE "Please enter the name of the file:",0
filename    BYTE 80 DUP(0)
fileHandle  HANDLE ?
byteCount DWORD ? ; holds counter
buffer BYTE BUFFER_SIZE DUP(?)
freq_array dw 256 dup(0) ;ARRAY OF FREQUENCIES OF EACH ASCII CHARACTER. 


.code
mov edi,OFFSET buffer 
mov ecx,LENGTHOF buffer

L1: 
mov  esi, offset freq_array
mov  al, [edi] 
mov  ah, 0       
shl  ax, 1            
add  si, ax  
inc  [ word ptr esi ]
add edi,TYPE BYTE 
loop L1
```

The buffer contains the content of a text file read in as a string. I have tested that part.
So not putting it here. I am getting the error `invalid use of register` at the line
`inc  [ word ptr esi ]`. How do I resolve that?

Comment: Does `inc word ptr [esi]` work, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks. Seems that worked. I have one more doubt. How do I print out the value of freq_array . Is there a shortcut for it. Or do I have to loop over it and print it one by one

Comment: @bittu: You loop over it, just like you would in C.

Comment: You can zero-extend your bytes to dword with `movzx eax, byte ptr [edi]`.  Then `add word ptr [freq_array + eax * 2],  1`.  In 32-bit code you can take advantage of its more powerful addressing modes (compared to 16-bit).  Also note that your code would be unsafe if `freq_array` spans a 64k boundary; `add si, ax` could wrap without doing carry-out into the high bits of ESI.